# Running a ruby script from another, weird error using "gets"

Tags: ruby, input, terminal, gets

I have written a ruby script that then calls another ruby script. The callee script is very long and has a lot of "gets" for input.

So what I do is open my unix terminal, call the caller script, which then does this simple line:

```
load "calleeScript.rb"
```

The calleeScript.rb has been simplified to just do this:

```
input = gets.chomp

print input
```

But it just gives me an error, like it can't handle gets. The error says:

> ./getsTest.rb:3:in `gets': No such file or directory - 5 (Errno::ENOENT)
>       from ./getsTest.rb:3

Even if I take out that gets it won't print/puts to the terminal. So any idea how I call one script that then calls another script (either relinquishing total control or forking), do some inputs/outputs, and still return to the previous script?

Comment: Can you boil this down to two files that are roughly five lines long each?

Comment: Hey sarnold, the first two blocks of code are literally the caller script and the callee script respectively (I whittled them down to isolate the issue). But as I said before, the problem seems to have gone away. I wish I knew what the issue was so I could post it here.

Comment: Oh, wow, that's one heck of a good whittling job. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Kernel#gets`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Kernel%3agets) is a convenience method that allows you to handle input both via standard input and via files.

If you call your script without any arguments, i.e. like this:

```
getsTest.rb
```

Then `Kernel#gets` reads its input from standard input. If, however, you call your script like this:

```
getsTest.rb foo.txt
```

Then `Kernel#gets` reads its input from a file named `foo.txt`.

In your case, `Kernel#gets` is complaining that it can't find a file named `5`, so presumably you called your script something like this:

```
getsTest.rb 5
```

If you want to read from some specific source, you should call [`IO#gets`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/IO%3agets) on that specific source. I suggest calling

```
$stdin.gets
```

Note: technically speaking, this is not a feature of `Kernel#gets` but rather of the `ARGF` magic constant. Basically, `Kernel#gets` just calls `ARGF.gets`.

Comment: It actually isn't the inclusion of a command line argument causing the issue (I accidentally posted the wrong error). When I call it without the parameter "5", it gives me the error:

Comment: $ ./getsTest.rb:1:in `gets': Input/output error (Errno::EIO)

And when I do a $stdin.gets in the callee script, it gives me the same error. I'm just trying to have the callee script be able to do gets in the terminal, because otherwise, I don't know how to allow the callee script to even get real-time input.

Comment: Strange though, it seems to be working now that I waiting a while and revisited it. So I'll put this as the solution since you gave me a lot of helpful information anyway!